# Choice in Mule Flow

Tags: java, mule

I am trying to divide my flow according to the data present in the Map, which is formed after using Mule Transformer XMLMapper And XML to Map..

I have already tried many ways.. One of them present in Mule site was..

```
 <choice>
 <when expression="#[message.payload['interface_id'] == 'BK131108.1655.000698']" evaluator="map-payload">
     <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
  </when>
 </choice>
```

But this also won't work. Any Help???

Comment: It may help to describe specifically what challenges you're running into rather than vaguely asking for help.

Comment: Matt.. With above expression Mule is throwing Error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```
evaluator="map-payload"
```

You are forcing the use of the old expression evaluation framework while providing a MEL expression.

After removing it, and if the message payload is a map that contains the `"interface_id"` key, then the expression should work.

Comment: Can you explain this.. Or provide any link for its explaination??

Comment: @Atmaram Not sure what "this" stands for in your question. In any case, here is a link for MEL: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

Comment: The above solution worked fine when I was running my flow in Mule.. But when I tried to run the same flow on tomcat, on linux machine I am getting error:

Comment: Error is: ERROR 2015-08-25 11:46:43,914 [[eig-1.0].BankServiceJMS.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.mule.routing.filters.ExpressionFilter.getFullExpression(ExpressionFilter.java:140)
        at org.mule.routing.filters.ExpressionFilter.accept(ExpressionFilter.java:104)
        at org.mule.routing.ChoiceRouter.selectProcessors(ChoiceRouter.java:35)
        at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:194)

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Please open a new question with the Mule config and the full stack trace.

Comment: New question link is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218281/choice-configuration-in-mule-flow-in-tomcat