# Choice Configuration in Mule Flow in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, mule

I am trying to divide my flow according to the data present in the Map, which is formed after using Mule Transformer XMLMapper And XML to Map.. Flow looks like at choice point is:

```
  <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.payload['interfaceId'] == 'BK131108.1655.000698']" >
            <processor-chain doc:name="AUB Encryption" />
            ...
        </when>
      ......
  </choice>
```

Same flow works fine when I run it on Mule Studio on Windows Machine.. But when I deploy the flow (with whole project) on tomcat on a linux machine i am getting error...

```
DEBUG 2015-08-25 11:46:43,908 [[eig-1.0].BankServiceJMS.stage1.02] com.comviva.mfs.eig.transformers.XmlToMap: The transformed object is of expected type. Type is: HashMap
ERROR 2015-08-25 11:46:43,914 [[eig-1.0].BankServiceJMS.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mule.routing.filters.ExpressionFilter.getFullExpression(ExpressionFilter.java:140)
    at org.mule.routing.filters.ExpressionFilter.accept(ExpressionFilter.java:104)
    at org.mule.routing.ChoiceRouter.selectProcessors(ChoiceRouter.java:35)
    at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.process(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:194)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.DefaultMessageProcessorChain.doProcess(DefaultMessageProcessorChain.java:99)
    at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.process(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:66)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.processNext(AbstractInterceptingMessageProcessorBase.java:105)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.process(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:111)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:158)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:43)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any Suggestion....

Comment: @David: Please check..

Comment: looks like ur payload doesnt have that 'interfaceId'. Could u try using a logger before this choice and print #[message.payload['interfaceId']] is working or not.

Comment: See if changing the expression to "#[message.payload.interfaceId == 'BK131108.1655.000698']" fixes it.

Comment: @tortoise : same is working on windows machine..

Comment: @TyroneVillaluna: I have tried with ur solution already.. same error is coming..

Comment: identify the payload just before the choice, make sure the field is actually there, use a logger for example

Comment: @GabrielDimech: I have already checked the same.. And for ur info iam loading my payload here...    {amount=10000, cpin=dd6fd61bfbe1ad90, transaction_time=26082015032728, MobiquityTXNID=WB150826.1527.C00005, mwacct=0731000017, interfaceId=BK131108.1655.000698, msisdn=0731000017, ....}

Comment: @GabrielDimech: More over same flow is working completely fine in windows machine.. With same request and same payload..

Comment: could you try adding a logger with expression = "#[message.payload['interfaceId']" before the choice? also, as a workaround, perhaps you can add the value to a flow var and then evaluate the flow var.

Comment: @GabrielDimech: Can you specify.. like I don't know how to print this particular expression, as I use echo.. and log.info.. Is any other way to print this???

Comment: <logger message="#[message.payload['interfaceId']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

Comment: You need to specify the Mule version you are using. Hard to help without this info.

Comment: Even better: copy the tree generated by `mvn dependency:tree` on your project in your question. I suspect missing or mis-matching dependencies.

Comment: @DavidDossot: I am using EE-3.4.1. And, my project built by ant.

Comment: @GabrielDimech: this logger is throwing error.. suggestion is showing that I have to add some config in Xpath..

Comment: @GabrielDimech: org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: BK131108.1655.000698.. Its printing ok now..

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Mule 3.4.1. at line 140, where the exception is thrown, is: `{` (see: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.4.1/core/src/main/java/org/mule/routing/filters/ExpressionFilter.java#L140 )

Thus, I suspect you're not packaging the WAR file properly, i.e. with the expected version of Mule. Please manually inspect `WEB-INF/lib` to see what `mule-*.jar` have been packaged and make sure all versions are consistent.

Comment: I checked, my lib folder was having mule-3.2.1-embedded.jar.. I changed it to mule-core-3.4.1.jar.. But then my app was not starting at all.. then tried with mule-common-3.4.1.jar... same problem... Any other suggestion...

Comment: Two suggestions: 1) Use Maven: it's impossible to manage Mule dependencies by hand. 2) Contact MuleSoft: they'll give you access to their Enterprise Maven repository, which you need to get the JARs of the EE version of Mule 3.4.1.